# Update query is not working properly with date in where clause from prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I am trying to update a record using prepared statement(JAVA). This is my code

```
query = "UPDATE TABLE SET ORDER_ID = ? WHERE CUST_CODE = ? AND ORDER_DATE = ?";
stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setInt(1, 20);
stmt.setString(2, "sk");
stmt.setObject(3, getCurrentTimeStamp('2015-07-18T13:32:56.971-0400'));
stmt.execute();
```

The getCurrentTimeStamp() is a method that returns OffsetDateTime of given string.

The problem here is that the update query doesn't work fine, and the value is not actually updated. Before and after the update the values or ORDER_ID are same.

There is no issues with the getCurrentTimeStamp() method as I am using it for other DML queries and it works fine. I think I have issues with the update query

Can someone help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `2015-07-18T13:32:56.971-0400` is a very precise timestamp from over four years ago. Are you sure that the record(s) you are trying to update have that exact value?

Comment: Yes they are same!!

Comment: OK. I assume your `CUST_CODE` value is correct. What about the name of your table? I don't see that in your SQL statement. Unless it's actually `TABLE`.

Comment: It is TABLE only !!

Comment: Use `stmt.executeUpdate();`.

Comment: Are you sure that order date (which is actually a timestamp) happened at that precise **milli** second? Did you get the time zone right? Can you manually run a SELECT statement with your SQL client using that exact timestamp to see if it returns anything?

Comment: What is your DBMS? In most databases I'm aware of, `table` is a reserved keyword; I would have expected an error with this code.

Comment: I seemed to have issues with the date insertion as told by @dave After insertion of the dateTime value there were some alterations at the db side. But, still even if I copy the same date and try it isn't working.The interesting part is that when I run the query in dbeaver it works just fine(i.e. with date value being copied from the table itself). But it fails to work through Java